# Data from RPC call from client-service to caller (GWT)

Tags: java, gwt, rpc

I can't explain the following situation:

I make an RPC call to load data from server files in to a list of serializable objects.

**The problem is the following:**

The call is executed perfectly fine as far as I can tell (that's why I didn't post the interfaces and the serverside code). When I set the list on the clientside everything is fine (I check the size in setData()). However when I want to assign the list to the object in the class calling I get an empty list (sizecheck returns nullpointer).

Here is the clientside code:

```
public class DataImportServiceClientImpl {
    private DataImportServiceAsync service;
    private List<Datarow> data;
    public DataImportServiceClientImpl(String url){
        this.service = GWT.create(DataImportService.class);
        ServiceDefTarget endpoint = (ServiceDefTarget) this.service;
        endpoint.setServiceEntryPoint(url);
        }

    public void readInput(String Auswertung){
        this.service.readInput(Auswertung, new DefaultCallback());
    }

    public List<Datarow> getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(List<Datarow> data) {
        this.data = data;
        System.out.println(data.size()); //returns the correct value
    }

    private class DefaultCallback implements AsyncCallback {

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
            System.out.println("An Error has occured!");
        }

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Object result) {
            if(result instanceof List<?>){
            List<Datarow> temp = (List<Datarow>) result;
            setData(temp);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

I call it here (this is obviously a different class):

```
    private DataImportServiceClientImpl importer = new DataImportServiceClientImpl(GWT.getModuleBaseURL()+"DataImport");
    private String Auswertung = "xyz";
    private List<Datarow> data = new ArrayList<Datarow>();

    public void onModuleLoad() {
        importer.readInput(Auswertung);
        data = importer.getData();
        System.out.println(importer.getData().size()); //returns Nullpointer = same for data.size()
```

Comment: Hint: "async" vs. sync/blocking

Comment: @Thomas Broyer Do you mean because its non blocking I want to access the data before it has been set, thus resulting in an empty list? If so what would be a better solution here?

Comment: @Kazoooie: Your program logic that involves the data you receive from an RPC call should continue only in `onFailure` and `onSuccess` methods. Everywhere else you have an unpredictable state: you simply don't know whether the data already arrived or not yet.

Comment: @Andrei Volgin: Yea thanks. I found that out when I added 1 object on initialization to the list in the clientservice class. I really don't want to create an instance of the caller in the clientservice class(not even a possibility). Guess I'll try using the observer pattern.

Comment: @AndreiVolgin Even worse than that: JS executes single-threaded, so even if `readInput` response would arrive before the `getData()` line were executed, the `onSuccess` would be blocked until the end of `onModuleLoad` (when control flow is given back to the browser).

Comment: @ThomasBroyer:Good to know. Next time I'm doing this I am going to create a mysql database. I read that you had to host the app on tomcat and do some other stuff which put me off a little but it would be worth the effort.